# 'Could not fsync file' while running VACUUM FULL on a table

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm getting an error for around half of my tables in Postgres while trying to run VACUUM FULL.

For example, I have a table named 'qwerty', and when i try to vacuum it i get the following error:

> ERROR:  could not fsync file "base/16392/3655838": Input/output error

But for some reason, when i run:

```
SELECT pg_relation_filepath('qwerty');
```

It shows the file path as another:

```
base/16392/3391046
```

I cant seem to find any information about this online, I would be more than glad if anybody could help!

Comment: Firstly, this isn't a programming question, but rather a database one, and as such belongs on [dba](https://dba,stackexchange.com), not here on [so].  Secondly it's impossible for us to tell you a conclusive answer with the information provided.  Is the disk full, by any chance? Is the file-system corrupt? Does the disk have other I/O issues?  Consider moving your question to **dba** and add the details I'm asking for ....

Answer (score 0):

The file that PostgreSQL tries to sync is probably the *new* file created during `VACUUM (FULL)`. This system call persists the file to disk so that it cannot get lost during a crash.

Perhaps your disk is having hardware problems, or you are using a file system that has problems with that (which you shouldn't do).